# Xcode Linker Issue - Other LD Flags won't clear

Tags: xcode, linker, flags

I am a noob and am having an issue with linker flags.

I tried building my own ssh2 libraries, and then afterwards I cloned a git repository with a project in the libraries already built.

Before I downloaded the compiled binaries, I was building with gcrypt and added the -lgrcrypt library to the other linker flags.

With this new library set that I am using, I no longer require gycrpt and so I removed the linker flags. However that did not clear the linker options.  I am still getting all of the old linker flags in spite of clearing them in the project properties.

The error shows that the -lgrypt is still being processed as a linker flag:

> -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -lgcrypt

How can I reset the linker flags to what they were?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the simulator that you are using, is it ios 6 or above. because the linker is saying that the error is related to the simulator. the framwork only runs on ios 6 or above simulator.

Comment: Sorry, this is the error message:  ld: library not found for -lgcrypt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).  The same pre-built libs compile in another project, it is just that I have buggered up this project with the other linker flags and now it is still looking for grcrypt lib which I am not using.

Comment: Thanks Code Monkey -- I guess that's all that's left to do -- porting to a new project.  I ran across another poster in a different forum who had the same problems with search LIBRARY SEARCH PATH -- still kept the same values after removing them in the GUI.  I am a complete noob -- is there anyway that I can mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: I just put the comment as an answer so you can mark that as the correct answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i presume you have checked the flags and removed the path for that lib in your target level of the project, and also have clean the build and removed the previouse builds from organizer and inside xcode, and also have reset your simulator, and also have checked the project folder on your computer and removed that lib from the library folder of the project. these are the necessary steps and if you have done all of these then i cant think of anything else other than port your code to a new project and try to compile again. good luck my friend.

Comment: Thanks again Code Monkey.  There was a happy ending.  What I did was copy the whole project folder as a back up, and toyed around, deleting the derived data and all of the caches that I could think of.  I tried deleting all of the static libraries, and got into  a real mess with the linker.  So I just renamed the project folder to a backup name, and replaced it with the original backup.  On the off chance I did a build and the linker argument disappeared and it worked without porting it to a new project.  I don't know what happened there, but I am glad that it healed itself.

Comment: Awesome. So now you can get back to coding. Have fun my friend.